# yii 1.1 save $models in foreach, nothing happens

Tags: foreach, yii, save

find All Models like this:

```
$models=Termin::model()->findAll(
            array("condition"=>"status = 3"));
```

and than set new status with foreach:

```
foreach($models as $data) {

            $data->status=1;
            if($data->save())
            {
                echo 'saved';
            }
        }
```

but nothing happens ;(

Answer (score 1):

**Correction:**
From Yii 1.1 onwards you can use [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) for both update and save operations. [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) (your model's parent class) automatically determines if the current model (`$data` in your case) is a fresh record or it was retrieved from a db (with `$data->isNewRecord` property). If the record is fresh, `CActiveRecord` class will automatically use [insert()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#insert-detail) method and if it was retrieved from an existing recordset it will switch to [update()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#update-detail).

**Your question:** [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) method (from [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) parent class) have two optional parameters. One to run validations (as set in your model rules) before actually sending to the db handler for saving, and the other to specify which attributes you want to save. By default this validation is set to `true` - meaning: plain `$data->save()` method will run all your model level validations. If the validations fail, there would not be any attempt at writing the record, but instead will add error details to the model. You can fetch these errors by calling `$data->getErrors()` method on the model. (Note that [getErrors()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail) is from yet another parent class [CModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel))

If you call `$data->save(false)`, model validations [defined in your model's `rules()`] will not be run and the record will be passed on for the db handler for writing. This will come back with a success (or an exception, if there were any errors at the db level - e.g. foreign key / unique / other).

Hence, I would refactor your code as follows:

```
foreach($models as $data) {
    $data->status=1;

    try { // try catch block to capture db level mishaps

        if ($data->save(true)) { // run model validations and if success

            echo 'saved';

        } else { // model validations failed

            // Debug with var_dump($data->getErrors()) or Yii's CVarDumper class
            // And/Or Display error message to user

        }

    } catch (CException $ex) { // This will catch any errors thrown during db write

       // Debug with var_dump($ex)
       // And/Or Display error message to user

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution by my own.

In yii 1.1 its update() instead of save(). In yii 2 you can always use save() i thought!

Comment: You can use save() instead of update(). In your case probably save() failed because of some validation error and returned FALSE. You can get more information with $data->getErrors()

Comment: and most likely save(false) will work then as well as it will skip the validation. However I find that fixing the validation problem is usually the better option (with scenario's for example)